# the values on the graph in Grafana differ from the real ones

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I want to plot the signal to noise ratio (SNR).
My C++ application measures the signal/noise values and passes these values to Grafana 8.5 using the prometheus-spp library.
The values on the graph in Grafana do not correspond to the real values.

My C++ application measures the signal/noise values (SNR) and passes these values to Grafana using the prometheus-spp library.
Because SNR values can be negative, I use the Gauge counter.

My request looks something like this:

`delta(MyApp_gauge{Channel_type="Main",Metric_name="SNR_average",Channel_index="0"}[1m])`

As a result, with real SNR values about 18, I get a value of about 45 on the graph.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUqM4.png)

Perhaps I should make the request differently?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it's impossible to use the Gauge type counter together with the Increment() function and further process the results in Grafana using the delta() function. Well, or I don't know how to do it right. I just used the Set() function instead of Increment() and didn't use the delta() function in Grafana - after that my data was displayed correctly